# Errors were encountered while processing: nvidia-dkms-510

Tags: apt, nvidia, 22.04, additional-drivers

I'm getting a fault when I run apt upgrade. It faults on the nvidia 510 driver. It looks to me like it was built with a different gcc to the kernel but it's a bit beyond my abilities to debug what's going on. Can anyone help? I've put some relevant debugging information below. Let me know if there's anything else that can be helpful.

Output of apt update:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  fonts-opensymbol grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
The following packages will be upgraded:
  tzdata
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 333 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 tzdata all 2022f-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [333 kB]
Fetched 333 kB in 0s (2,044 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 225092 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2022f-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2022f-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (2022f-0ubuntu0.22.04.0) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-510 (510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-510.85.02 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-510.85.02 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-510.85.02 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-53-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-53-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-510.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-53-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-510 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-510 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up tzdata (2022f-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/London'
Local time is now:      Tue Nov 15 16:38:06 GMT 2022.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Nov 15 16:38:06 UTC 2022.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-53-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-510
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Looking at the mentioned make.log there is an unrecognised command line option
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mharden-sls=all’; did you mean ‘-mhard-float’?

make.log

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-510.85.02 for kernel 5.15.0-53-generic (x86_64)
Tue 15 Nov 16:37:57 GMT 2022
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-53-generic'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 8.5.0-0ubuntu4) 8.5.0
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
  ln -sf /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o_binary /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
  ln -sf /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel.o_binary /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel.o
 CONFTEST: hash__remap_4k_pfn
 CONFTEST: set_pages_uc
 CONFTEST: list_is_first
 CONFTEST: set_memory_uc
 CONFTEST: set_memory_array_uc
 CONFTEST: set_pages_array_uc
 CONFTEST: console_lock
 CONFTEST: acquire_console_sem
 CONFTEST: ioremap_cache
 CONFTEST: ioremap_wc
 CONFTEST: acpi_walk_namespace
 CONFTEST: sg_alloc_table
 CONFTEST: pci_get_domain_bus_and_slot
 CONFTEST: get_num_physpages
 CONFTEST: efi_enabled
 CONFTEST: pde_data
 CONFTEST: PDE_DATA
 CONFTEST: proc_remove
 CONFTEST: pm_vt_switch_required
 CONFTEST: xen_ioemu_inject_msi
 CONFTEST: phys_to_dma
 CONFTEST: get_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: dma_attr_macros
 CONFTEST: dma_map_page_attrs
 CONFTEST: write_cr4
 CONFTEST: of_get_property
 CONFTEST: of_find_node_by_phandle
 CONFTEST: of_node_to_nid
 CONFTEST: pnv_pci_get_npu_dev
 CONFTEST: of_get_ibm_chip_id
 CONFTEST: node_end_pfn
 CONFTEST: pci_bus_address
 CONFTEST: pci_stop_and_remove_bus_device
 CONFTEST: pci_remove_bus_device
 CONFTEST: register_cpu_notifier
 CONFTEST: cpuhp_setup_state
 CONFTEST: dma_map_resource
 CONFTEST: backlight_device_register
 CONFTEST: get_backlight_device_by_name
 CONFTEST: timer_setup
 CONFTEST: pci_enable_msix_range
 CONFTEST: kernel_read_has_pointer_pos_arg
 CONFTEST: kernel_write
 CONFTEST: kthread_create_on_node
 CONFTEST: of_find_matching_node
 CONFTEST: dma_direct_map_resource
 CONFTEST: dev_is_pci
 CONFTEST: tegra_get_platform
 CONFTEST: tegra_bpmp_send_receive
 CONFTEST: flush_cache_all
 CONFTEST: vmf_insert_pfn
 CONFTEST: jiffies_to_timespec
 CONFTEST: ktime_get_raw_ts64
 CONFTEST: ktime_get_real_ts64
 CONFTEST: full_name_hash
 CONFTEST: hlist_for_each_entry
 CONFTEST: pci_enable_atomic_ops_to_root
 CONFTEST: vga_tryget
 CONFTEST: pgprot_decrypted
 CONFTEST: cc_mkdec
 CONFTEST: iterate_fd
 CONFTEST: seq_read_iter
 CONFTEST: sg_page_iter_page
 CONFTEST: unsafe_follow_pfn
 CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_get
 CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_put_unlocked
 CONFTEST: set_close_on_exec
 CONFTEST: add_memory_driver_managed
 CONFTEST: device_property_read_u64
 CONFTEST: devm_of_platform_populate
 CONFTEST: of_dma_configure
 CONFTEST: of_property_count_elems_of_size
 CONFTEST: of_property_read_variable_u8_array
 CONFTEST: i2c_new_client_device
 CONFTEST: i2c_unregister_device
 CONFTEST: of_get_named_gpio
 CONFTEST: devm_gpio_request_one
 CONFTEST: gpio_direction_input
 CONFTEST: gpio_direction_output
 CONFTEST: gpio_get_value
 CONFTEST: gpio_set_value
 CONFTEST: gpio_to_irq
 CONFTEST: icc_get
 CONFTEST: icc_put
 CONFTEST: icc_set_bw
 CONFTEST: dma_set_coherent_mask
 CONFTEST: acpi_bus_get_device
 CONFTEST: get_task_ioprio
 CONFTEST: address_space_init_once
 CONFTEST: kbasename
 CONFTEST: vzalloc
 CONFTEST: wait_on_bit_lock_argument_count
 CONFTEST: bitmap_clear
 CONFTEST: usleep_range
 CONFTEST: radix_tree_empty
 CONFTEST: radix_tree_replace_slot
 CONFTEST: pnv_npu2_init_context
 CONFTEST: cpumask_of_node
 CONFTEST: ioasid_get
 CONFTEST: migrate_vma_setup
 CONFTEST: drm_dev_unref
 CONFTEST: drm_reinit_primary_mode_group
 CONFTEST: get_user_pages_remote
 CONFTEST: get_user_pages
 CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_lookup
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_state_ref_counting
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_prime_res_obj
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_connector_dpms
 CONFTEST: drm_connector_funcs_have_mode_in_name
 CONFTEST: drm_framebuffer_get
 CONFTEST: drm_dev_put
 CONFTEST: drm_format_num_planes
 CONFTEST: drm_connector_for_each_possible_encoder
 CONFTEST: drm_rotation_available
 CONFTEST: drm_vma_offset_exact_lookup_locked
 CONFTEST: nvhost_dma_fence_unpack
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_of_node_to_nid
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_sme_active
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_swiotlb_map_sg_attrs
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_swiotlb_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present___close_fd
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_close_fd
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_get_unused_fd
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_get_unused_fd_flags
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_nvhost_get_default_device
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_nvhost_syncpt_unit_interface_get_byte_offset
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_nvhost_syncpt_unit_interface_get_aperture
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_tegra_dce_register_ipc_client
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_tegra_dce_unregister_ipc_client
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_tegra_dce_client_ipc_send_recv
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_dram_clk_to_mc_clk
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_get_dram_num_channels
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_tegra_dram_types
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_present_kthread_create_on_node
 CONFTEST: file_operations
 CONFTEST: file_inode
 CONFTEST: kuid_t
 CONFTEST: dma_ops
 CONFTEST: swiotlb_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: noncoherent_swiotlb_dma_ops
 CONFTEST: vm_fault_has_address
 CONFTEST: backlight_properties_type
 CONFTEST: vm_insert_pfn_prot
 CONFTEST: vmf_insert_pfn_prot
 CONFTEST: vm_ops_fault_removed_vma_arg
 CONFTEST: vmbus_channel_has_ringbuffer_page
 CONFTEST: device_driver_of_match_table
 CONFTEST: device_of_node
 CONFTEST: node_states_n_memory
 CONFTEST: kmem_cache_has_kobj_remove_work
 CONFTEST: sysfs_slab_unlink
 CONFTEST: proc_ops
 CONFTEST: timespec64
 CONFTEST: vmalloc_has_pgprot_t_arg
 CONFTEST: acpi_fadt_low_power_s0
 CONFTEST: mm_has_mmap_lock
 CONFTEST: pci_channel_state
 CONFTEST: pci_dev_has_ats_enabled
 CONFTEST: mt_device_gre
 CONFTEST: remove_memory_has_nid_arg
 CONFTEST: address_space
 CONFTEST: backing_dev_info
 CONFTEST: mm_context_t
 CONFTEST: vm_fault_t
 CONFTEST: mmu_notifier_ops_invalidate_range
 CONFTEST: migrate_vma_added_flags
 CONFTEST: make_device_exclusive_range
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_present
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_bus_type
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_irq
 CONFTEST: drm_bus_has_get_name
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_device_list
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_legacy_dev_list
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_set_busid
 CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_connectors_changed
 CONFTEST: drm_init_function_args
 CONFTEST: drm_helper_mode_fill_fb_struct
 CONFTEST: drm_master_drop_has_from_release_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_unload_has_int_return_type
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_crtc_destroy_state_has_crtc_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_plane_destroy_state_has_plane_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_mode_object_find_has_file_priv_arg
 CONFTEST: dma_buf_owner
 CONFTEST: drm_connector_list_iter
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_helper_swap_state_has_stall_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_prime_flag_present
 CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_has_resv
 CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_async_flip
 CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_pageflip_flags
 CONFTEST: drm_format_modifiers_present
 CONFTEST: drm_vma_node_is_allowed_has_tag_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_vma_offset_node_has_readonly
 CONFTEST: drm_display_mode_has_vrefresh
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_master_set_has_int_return_type
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_free_object
 CONFTEST: drm_prime_pages_to_sg_has_drm_device_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_driver_has_gem_prime_callbacks
 CONFTEST: drm_crtc_atomic_check_has_atomic_state_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_gem_object_vmap_has_map_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_plane_atomic_check_has_atomic_state_arg
 CONFTEST: drm_device_has_pdev
 CONFTEST: drm_crtc_state_has_no_vblank
 CONFTEST: drm_mode_config_has_allow_fb_modifiers
 CONFTEST: dma_resv_add_fence
 CONFTEST: dma_resv_reserve_fences
 CONFTEST: reservation_object_reserve_shared_has_num_fences_arg
 CONFTEST: dom0_kernel_present
 CONFTEST: nvidia_vgpu_kvm_build
 CONFTEST: nvidia_grid_build
 CONFTEST: nvidia_grid_csp_build
 CONFTEST: pm_runtime_available
 CONFTEST: pci_class_multimedia_hd_audio
 CONFTEST: drm_available
 CONFTEST: drm_atomic_available
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_refcount_inc
 CONFTEST: is_export_symbol_gpl_refcount_dec_and_test
 CONFTEST: drm_alpha_blending_available
 CONFTEST: ib_peer_memory_symbols
  cc -Wp,-MMD,/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/.nv.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -I./ubuntu/include -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -fcf-protection=none -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -mfunction-return=thunk-extern -fno-jump-tables -mharden-sls=all -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-main -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-5 -pg -mrecord-mcount -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-alloc-size-larger-than -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -I/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/common/inc -I/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build -Wall -MD -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-error -Wno-format-extra-args -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DNVRM -DNV_VERSION_STRING=\"510.85.02\" -Wno-unused-function -Wuninitialized -fno-strict-aliasing -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DNV_UVM_ENABLE -DNV_SPECTRE_V2=0 -DNV_KERNEL_INTERFACE_LAYER -I/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia -DNVIDIA_UNDEF_LEGACY_BIT_MACROS -UDEBUG -U_DEBUG -DNDEBUG  -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize=shift -fsanitize=bool -fsanitize=enum  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"nv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"nvidia"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_nvidia -c -o /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/nv.o /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/nv.c
  cc -Wp,-MMD,/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/.nv-pci.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -I./ubuntu/include -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -fcf-protection=none -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -mfunction-return=thunk-extern -fno-jump-tables -mharden-sls=all -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-main -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -gdwarf-5 -pg -mrecord-mcount -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-alloc-size-larger-than -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -I/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/common/inc -I/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build -Wall -MD -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-error -Wno-format-extra-args -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DNVRM -DNV_VERSION_STRING=\"510.85.02\" -Wno-unused-function -Wuninitialized -fno-strict-aliasing -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -DNV_UVM_ENABLE -DNV_SPECTRE_V2=0 -DNV_KERNEL_INTERFACE_LAYER -I/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia -DNVIDIA_UNDEF_LEGACY_BIT_MACROS -UDEBUG -U_DEBUG -DNDEBUG  -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize=shift -fsanitize=bool -fsanitize=enum  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"nv_pci"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"nvidia"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_nvidia -c -o /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/nv-pci.o /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/nv-pci.c
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mharden-sls=all’; did you mean ‘-mhard-float’?
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/nv.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mharden-sls=all’; did you mean ‘-mhard-float’?
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build/nvidia/nv-pci.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1903: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.85.02/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-53-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:82: modules] Error 2
```

Output on ubuntu-drivers devices

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000013C2sv00001043sd00008508bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-520 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

uname -a

```
Linux docker2 5.15.0-53-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

uname -rspo

```
Linux 5.15.0-53-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

cat /etc/lsb-release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
```

I installed the nvidia drivers from the additional drivers dialog. 515 seems to be available. Should I switch to that?

Comment: This looks to be Bug #1977620.

I still wonder if it's yet recommended to switch up to the 515 drivers?

Answer (score 0):

The Make log reports:

```
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 8.5.0-0ubuntu4) 8.5.0
```

You should make sure that gcc 11 is installed:

```
sudo apt install gcc-11
```

And that it is the default when your user runs `gcc`:

```
gcc --version
```